# how to connect to socket.io on nodejs server using flutter?

Tags: node.js, express, flutter, dart, socket.io

I am developing a backend using node js and express framework and I will use socket.io in order to make a realtime connection between the server and the client ( flutter app ).

I have created a socket.io configuration on the server-side code and this is the code snippet:

```
const server = app.listen(port);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);



    io.on('connection' , client => {
        console.log('one connected');
    });
```

and on the client side:

```dart
SocketIO socketIO;


socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO(SERVER_URL, '/');

    socketIO.init().then(
          (result) async {



            await socketIO.subscribe('connection', (){});
            await socketIO.connect();

          },
        );
```

the problem that I can't see one connected logged in the console of the node app.

it doesn't throw any error on the client-side and I want to know if I am on the right way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After searching I found that the solution was to create my server using http plugin.